# С# Конвертер для календаря

Tags: c#, wpf

Всем привет. Надеюсь вы мне поможете. Я делаю календарь, даты которого можно выделять цветом при помощи `IValueConverter`.

```
class SetColorDayConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public static Dictionary<DateTime, string> dict = new Dictionary<DateTime, string>();

        static SetColorDayConverter()
        {
            dict.Add(new DateTime(2015, 5, 6), "Patrick's birthday");
            dict.Add(new DateTime(2015, 5, 7), "Susan 's birthday");
            dict.Add(new DateTime(2015, 5, 8), "Catherine's birthday");
        }

        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            string text;
            if (!dict.TryGetValue((DateTime)value, out text))
                text = null;
            return text;
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Стиль

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="primitives:CalendarDayButton">
                    <ControlTemplate.Resources>
                        <local:SetColorDayConverter x:Key="conv"/>
                    </ControlTemplate.Resources>
                    <Grid>
                        ...
                        <Rectangle x:Name="SetColorDayBackground"  Fill="#80FF0000" />
                    </Grid>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>                                              
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Converter={StaticResource conv}}" Value="{x:Null}">
                            <Setter TargetName="SetColorDayBackground" Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden" />
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
```

При запуске, даты отрисовываются правильно, но проблема в том, если во время работы программы программно добавить новую дату `dict.Add()`, то в календаре она не отрисуется до тех пор, пока не сменить месяц в календаре.

Answer (score 1):

Потому что ваша коллекция никак не сообщает о своем изменении, попробуйте вместо Dictonary в вашей коллекции использовать коллекцию поддерживающую INotifyCollectionChanged, пример можно найти тут [.NET ObservableDictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5663395/net-observabledictionary)

Comment: Mirdin, все равно не отрисовывает, использовал 'ObservableDictionary' из примеров по твоей ссылке

Comment: @Darkleon, а к чему у вас тригер биндится, из примера не понятно. Может, там стоит указать свойство Path